# Running artisan commands along with npm commands

Tags: laravel, npm

I am trying to find a simple way to run `npm dev` and `php artisan serve` using a single command. I have created a new script within `package.json` and run the command via `npm run start`. This may come as obvious to most, but I thought it was an interesting idea that obviously can be expanded upon.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the command below in case anyone has this idea down the road and doesn't want to spend an hour looking into it like I did.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "(php artisan serve) & npm run dev"
}
```